# Looking for WiFi Phase and RSSI data

Tags: digital-communications, localization

I'm not sure if this is right platform to post . I am researching on WiFi Localization algorithms using Machine learning and was wondering if anyone knows any dataset  which is publicly available. Some companies do post them online   - > https://www.deepsig.io/datasets   (datasets here are generated on GNURadio )

The dataset I'm looking can be like this

AP_location | Rssi of Client | Client_location | PhaseValues(if avaialable)

Thanks

Comment: what would "phase value" be? Makes little sense, since "phase" is a relative thing; and in the case of OFDM systems like Wifi, even less sense, since these systems are employed *exactly* when the signal is wider than the coherency bandwidth of the channel, and thus you get different phases on different parts of your spectrum.

Comment: also, since this all happens due to multipath, that dataset needs to contain a map of obstacles and reflectors, too, otherwise there's just too many degrees of freedom your ML needs to learn... this is a bit of an old topic, and numerous publications of the past have shown that, to little surprise, completely blind location estimation using ML doesn't work very well in indoor environments.

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=machine%20learning%20802.11%20location